# Error: URI formats are not supported. c#

Tags: c#

My code here:

```
        StreamReader sr;
        sr = File.OpenText(@"http://k1.besaba.com/Lic.rtf");

        richTextBox1.Rtf = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
```

Why error Additional information: URI formats are not supported. Please help me. Thank you. Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/51at6.png

Answer (score 0):

`File.OpenText()` is meant to open a file stored locally on the file system. You would want to do something like this:

```
var webClient = new WebClient(); //Make sure to reference System.Net
richTextBox1.Rtf = client.DownloadString("http://k1.besaba.com/Lic.rtf");
```